# How to properly align three-level enumerate 1. 1.1. 1.1.1

Tags: horizontal-alignment, margins, enumerate

I've created my environment, and modified the enumerate command:

```
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\arabic{enumi}.}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.\arabic{enumiii}.}

\newenvironment{packed_enum}{
\begin{enumerate}
\setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
}{\end{enumerate}}
```

And this is what i get:

[image: Latex Problem]

The first two levels align properly (I've marked it with blue line), but the third level starts too much on the left (red line). Can You help me fix this?
I've tried something like this  (also with changing `labelsep` to `\leftmargin`):

```
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\arabic{enumi}.}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\setlength{\labelsep{5ex}\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.\arabic{enumiii}.}
```

or this:

```
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\arabic{enumi}.}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\hbox{\hspace{5ex}\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.\arabic{enumiii}.}}
```

but neither helped.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With the help of `enumitem`

```
\newenvironment{packed_enum}{%
  \renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\arabic{enumi}.}%
  \renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.}%
  \renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.\arabic{enumiii}.}%
  \begin{enumerate}[itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt,leftmargin=*]%
  }{\end{enumerate}}
```

The option `leftmargin=*` ensures that the label is aligned with the surrounding text. Note that I also inserted all `\renewcommand`s inside the `\newenvironment` to make the changes only locally.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{packed_enum}{%
  \renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\arabic{enumi}.}%
  \renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.}%
  \renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.\arabic{enumiii}.}%
  \begin{enumerate}[itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt,leftmargin=*]%
  }{\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}

\begin{packed_enum}
  \item First level
  \begin{packed_enum}
    \item Second level
    \begin{packed_enum}
      \item Third level
    \end{packed_enum}
  \end{packed_enum}
\end{packed_enum}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you're loading the [`enumitem`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/enumitem) package, you might as well use the commands it provides for making list-type environments, namely

```
\newlist{packed_enum}{enumerate}{5}
\setlist[packed_enum]{label*=\arabic*.,leftmargin=*}
```

Here's a complete MWE that produces the same output as the other answer.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{packed_enum}{enumerate}{5}
\setlist[packed_enum]{label*=\arabic*.,leftmargin=*}

\begin{document}

\begin{packed_enum}
    \item First level
    \begin{packed_enum}
        \item Second level
        \begin{packed_enum}
            \item Third level
        \end{packed_enum}
    \end{packed_enum}
\end{packed_enum}

\end{document}
```